# SQL code for retrieving values of column starting using wildcard

Tags: sql, wildcard

I want to look for values in variable/column which start with 'S' and has 'gg' in between.

For instance `Staggered` is a word which starts with alphabet S and has gg in between the word.

so what sql query to write to get the result.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the fact that you did not provide much meta information (which database?), I'll just show the following:

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
WHERE <columnname> LIKE 'S%gg%';
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

As the target database is not mentioned, I will answer with Oracle syntax:

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where COL_NAME like 'S%gg%'
```

Comment: That is actually standard SQL, not specific to Oracle

Comment: You are probably right, what I meant was that it surely works on Oracle ,,, but if you try it on say MS Access it will probably fail as another wild card character must be used...

Comment: The question is tagged with `sql` so answers with standard SQL are absolutely fine. If Ankit uses a DBMS that ignores the SQL standard for simple things like that, he should have mentioned that in the question.